# How do I attach event handlers using jQuery only to newly added elements?

Tags: jquery

There are objects where I have attached some events to.
After some point, I create some more of those items and I want them also to be attached to the same events.

If select elements using a jQuery selector and attach the handler to the event, the older object will have the same handler attached multiple times to their event.

What's the proper way of doing this?

Comment: Can you not bind the handlers to the domElement when they are created?

Comment: @dhinesh, if about that, he could use `live` that the other members pointed to, but I think even `live` does not literally solve his/her problem, Hey Odys the proper way is to unbind event handlers for old ones and then bind with `live` for all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would go like this about it:

```
$(".element").unbind("click").live("click", function () {
// ...
});
```

and by that you unbind older 'click' event handlers and bind old and new ones only once with `live`.

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps you should consider adding the handlers with [`live`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) instead. This way, you declare the handler once and it remains in effect for all matching elements, now and in the future.

If for some reason this is not acceptable, a quick and dirty solution would be (example for the `click` handler):

```
$(".elements").unbind("click").bind("click", function () {
    // ...
});
```

A much better solution (again, without `live`) would be the [`hasEventListener`](https://github.com/sebastien-p/jquery.hasEventListener) plugin. Read the documentation, or play with its [sandbox on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sebastienp/eHGqB/).

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way would be to use [`.live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) to keep your handlers binded for existing and any possible future elements that match given selector.

Answer (score 1):

Use a namespace for your events, like so:

`$('a').bind('click.customNS', function(){...})`

and then, whenever you create a new element, unbind all of your namespaces events, and rebind, like so:

```
$('a').unbind('click.customNS');
$('a').bind('click.customNS', function(){...});
```

alternatively, use `.live('click', function(){..});`, which will automatically "bind" events to any newly created element, matchin your jQuery selector. This does not work on non-CSS compliant selectors, though. (jQuery special parent-selectors, for instance)